# AJAX Post to another Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a AJAX Post.
What i am trying to do is transfer the variable campos[i] to the test.php.

Script:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= <?php  echo $count - 1  ?>; i++) {

                        note[i] = jQuery('.bool#A' + i),
                            note[i].text(bounds.contains(accounts[i]));


                        if (bounds.contains(accounts[i])) {

                            $.ajax({

                                data: {'campos': campos[i]},
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: "test",
                                success: function () {
                                    alert("action performed successfully"); 
                                    $("#campos").load("test");
                                }

                            });
                        }


                    }
```

test.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: your url says test, not 'test.php'

Comment: yes i know, i am working with yii2 too and if I put test.php it won't go to that page.

Comment: Fire up your browser's inspector, and take a look at the data being sent in the request. Debugging will help solve your issue.

Comment: does it post if you comment out your `if` block?

Comment: should this line `note[i] = jQuery('.bool#A' + i),` have a semi-colon at the end..? instead of a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url must be test.php (if you don't have a route for it).
Your success callback should have data as response parameter.
You should append (`$("#campos").HTML(data.something)`) instead of doing another XHR request `$.load`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: .htaccess conflict?

Comment: I am working with yii2 so idk... maybe
thats why it must be test and not test.php

Comment: If you are using chrome, look for your xhr request (network tab in developer toolbar) and see what is the response. Also echo something on your test.php file to make sure it's that the file you're reaching.

Comment: maybe is because i am using yii2 and i need to do this a different way...

Comment: That means you're not reaching test.php file. 
yourwebsite.com/test.php does not exist. You need to update the url parameter in order to match the file path of test.php.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing a POST be sure to stringify your parameter.

```
 $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"campos": "'+ campos[i] '"}',
    method: 'POST',
    url: "your url here!",
    success: function () {
        alert("action performed successfully"); 
        $("#campos").load("test");
    }
});
```